# Identify cached data for a specific query in data cache

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, buffer-pool, page-life-expectancy

I'm trying to identify, if possible, how long it takes for data being cached by a stored procedure to be taken out of the cache.

I know there is the PLE counter in `sys.dm_os_performance_counters`, but I think in my scenario that won't help me very much.

*Disclaimer, all of this was handed down to me to improve:*

I have a stored procedure which returnes about 250 Mb of data into the cache, when being ran by one user. The procedure returns user-specific information, so the procedure is called with a `@userID` input parameter.

From the data returned by this stored procedure (about 3000 rows) it displays row-specific information, for one row at a time. There is a functionality that when a user presses a "Next" button in the application UI it goes and gets the row-specific information for the next row in the result and so on.

Due to the data already being in cache, when testing with a single user the response time was ~1 second, because all of the 250 Mb would fit in cache without any problem and not being cleared very fast.

I've tested the procedure with a cold cache and the execution time was about 10 seconds to return the data.

Now, I have about 30 users running the stored procedure in the same time interval and they have reported experiencing about a 10 second delay when pressing the "Next" button.

Surprisingly this is the same exec. time when pushing data into the cache and because there are 30 users, my conclusion at this point is because the total amount of data being pushed into cache is about 7Gb (total server memory is 16Gb), the data gets pushed in and out of cache very often.

This is all just a theory at this point, but I'm trying to identify some metrics that directly point at this being the issue. I know PLE could be an indicator, but is there anything that could be more specific, for a query for example.

My recommendation would be to re-write the stored procedure in a more efficient way, but that would take lots of time and business is not very interested in spending time for that. If I can prove, with this theory of mine, that there is no way, then they might allow for a re-write of the procedure.

Oh, and crazy enough, they're not very happy about increasing server memory either. *Talking about not giving me options..*

Answer (score 1):

If the goal of your question is to determine if your stored procedure is having to do physical reads to satisfy the query (instead of retrieving the data from memory), you might be able to use the following query in the stored procedure to capture the physical reads during execution and possibly save that information for auditing purposes

```
declare @start_reads bigint
select @start_reads = reads from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id = @@spid

-- Your query here 

select reads - @start_reads from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id = @@spid
```

Comment: Yes, that could do the trick. I will try, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just doing some quick math here, but 250Mb of data is about 31,000 pages, meaning that each row is being pulled from 10 pages.

You only have two options when it comes to resource constraints: use less or add more.

In this case, if you cannot add more memory, you should look to rewrite the code to reduce the amount of data being returned. I would do that before adding memory, because adding memory won't fix the issue of inefficient design.

Inefficient code and design will always bring hardware to it's knees at some point. You may go from 30 to 300 users in a year, it would be better to look at code now and not later.

Comment: Totally agree on the redesign and re-coding of the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Data pages in the Buffer Pool are shared across any number of queries, so you can't really narrow down which data pages go with which particular queries. But, you can at least identify which tables / indexed views the data in memory belongs to. And, if there aren't many (or any) other queries against the table(s) being selected from in this particular stored procedure, then you can get a sense of how much data it pulls in. And if you store the `file_id` and `page_id` values in a local temp table, you might be able to tell the difference (to a degree, perhaps) between the data for two different `@UserID` values, assuming that the data for the two `@UserID` values would be on different datapages, which may or may not be the case, or it may sometimes be the case.

Try the following query. You need to run it within the database that contains the Stored Procedure in question since the system catalog views are per each database, even though `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors` is instance-level.

You might need to uncomment the `WHERE` condition related to the TableName to narrow things down to what is being used in that Stored Procedure.

```
USE [database_containing_problem_stored_procedure];

SELECT
    SchemaName = sh.name, 
    TableName = so.name, 
    IndexName = ISNULL(si.name, N'<heap>'), 
    PartitionNumber = sp.partition_number,
    IndexID = si.index_id,
    PartitionRows = sp.[rows],
    TotalPages = au.total_pages,
    AllocationUnitType = au.type_desc,
    [DataCompresson] = sp.data_compression_desc,
    bp.*
FROM   sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors bp
INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units au
        ON au.allocation_unit_id = bp.allocation_unit_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions sp
        ON au.container_id = IIF(au.[type] = 2, sp.[partition_id], sp.[hobt_id])
INNER JOIN sys.indexes si
        ON si.[object_id] = sp.[object_id]
       AND si.index_id = sp.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects so
        ON sp.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sh
        ON so.[schema_id] = sh.[schema_id]
WHERE bp.database_id = DB_ID()
AND   sh.[name] <> N'sys'
--AND   so.[name] IN (N'TableToFilterOn_1', N'TableToFilterOn_2')
ORDER BY sh.[name], so.[name], si.[name], bp.page_type;
```